Change Android Device Time Programmatically Without Rooting the Device
On a  Honeywell Chainway C71 device (Android 6) we used to change the time programmatically like this:
   cmd = $"am broadcast -a com.rscja.android.updateSystemTime --ei YEAR {now.Year}" +
                              $" --ei MONTH {now.Month - 1} --ei DAY_OF_MONTH {now.Day} --ei HOUR_OF_DAY {now.Hour}" +
                              $" --ei MINUTE {now.Minute} --ei SECOND {now.Second} --ei MILLISECOND {now.Millisecond}";

AdbClient.Instance.ExecuteRemoteCommand(cmd, device, receiver);

When we switched to a newer device Honeywell EDA 52 (Android 11) com.rsja.android package is not available anymore.
Is there any way to change system time programmatically without rooting the device? Or is there any other ways to change the time on the Android 11 device?
Some of the packages available:
package:com.android.providers.calendar
package:com.android.providers.media
package:com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
package:
package:com.honeywell.tools.deviceconfig
package:com.honeywell.settings
package:android
package:com.qualcomm.wfd.service
package:com.honeywell.systools.unattendedsetting
package:com.google.android.deskclock
package:com.honeywell.tools.smu
package:com.google.android.gm
package:com.honeywell.tools.appsconfig
package:com.android.providers.settings
package:com.google.android.calendar
package:com.android.


Are you able to specify an ntp server in the device settings? If so then set up one yourself that broadcasts the time you wish the device has to have.

unless honeywell provides some api the only other thing you can do without root it create a device admin app. Device Policy Manager has an api to set the time

@SpaceTrucker Thansk for your suggestions. I don't think I can specify the ntp server without root.
